# Validation using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to give validation to both fields email and name but only email is getting validated and its not checking for name field. I am not able to find what is wrong in the code.

```
<html>
<body>
  <form name="myForm">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email2">
    <br>
    Name: <input type="text" name=" fname">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validateForm()">submit</button>
    <br> email
    <div id="email1"></div>
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;

    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
    }

    var email1 = document.getElementById("email2").value;

    document.getElementById("email1").innerHTML=email1;

    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (y==null ||y=="") {
      alert("name must be filled");
      return false;    
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because if email is invalid `return false;` will return the control and the code below will not be executed.

Comment: You can use HTML5 validations `<input type="email" name="email" required />`

Comment: The validation should be on the form's submit handler since the form can be submitted without clicking the submit button. Giving any form control a name of "submit" will make it impossible to call the form's *submit* method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name=" fname">
```

There is a space before fname.That is why it is not working.You can try simple solution like this

Comment: Name: <input type="text" name="fname" required>

Answer (score 1):

You have missed giving id to Name: `<input type="text" name=" fname">` Assign ID to `Name: <input type="text" name=" fname" id="fname">`.

As  `document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;` this requires element id to fetch value.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional boolean to check your validation

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    //Additional boolean
    var success = true;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        success = false;
    }
   var email1= document.getElementById("email2").value;
       document.getElementById("email1").innerHTML=email1;

     var y = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (y==null ||y=="") {
            alert("name must be filled");
            success = false;

    }
    return success;
    }
```